# Static Fluid pressure

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Refrence:- If there is a weight force $Mg$ on a box of area $A$ then pressure on box will be $Mg/A$. In another case box is on ground in equilibrium, so there will be two equal and opposite forces on box. In that case pressure would be 2Mg/A. Similarly in a container of height 'H' and area '1 m² which is full of fluid (fluid is in equilibrium) will have force of 'pgH' on the fluid at base, so pressure will also be 'pgH/1' (as base area=1 m²)

Now my question is:- as fluid at base is in equilibrium, there is an equal and opposite force which if equal to pgH so pressure due to this force will be pgH/1 .Now if we calculate total pressure than it should be 2pgH/1 (pressure from Mg + pressure from reaction force) but it is actually measured as pgH/1. Why is it so?

Comment: Note that dimensionally speaking, $\rho gh$ itself is the pressure which comes from force being $\rho gV$. There is no need to divide $\rho gh$ by $1m^2$.

Comment: "*In that case pressure would be 2Mg/A.*" The premise is incorrect. You can't add forces pointing in opposite directions. The compressive stress within the box is a uniform $Mg/A$, assuming its own weight is negligible compared to the force $Mg$.

Answer (score 0):

The question can be simplified by considering a brick with a mass such that it exerts a force of 1 Newton on the surface it is resting on. If we place a spring between the brick and the surface and there is a reaction force of -1 Newton from the surface, is the total force on the spring 2 Newtons?

The total net force on the centre of mass of the spring is actually zero, because the two opposing forces cancel each other out. This is confirmed by the fact that the spring remains stationary (when everything is in equilibrium), as any net force would cause it to accelerate.